# Exposing entities through services and partial responses

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, rest

What do you think about exposing domain entities through services? I tried it in an application, but I came to the conclusion that exposing domain model  to the client is not such a good idea.

Advantages:

- Really easy to transport data from-to client
- List item
- (De)Serialization is really easy: just put jackson in the classpath and it will handle it. No extra logic is needed.
- No need to duplicate entities POJOs. At least in early stages, the API resources will be pretty much the same as the domain model.

Disadvantages:

- The API's get very tightly coupled to the model and you can't change the model without affecting the API
- Partial responses. There are cases where you don't want to return all the fields of the entities, just some of them. How do you accomplish it?

So, let's take the following REST example. The following API declares that GET on the user resource returns the following information.
GET
/users/12

```
{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Poe"
    "address":"my street"
}
```

Usually, I would create a  User entity, a user service to return the user and a REST controller to serve the request like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return userService.findById(id);
}
```

Should I avoid returning the User entity? 
If yes, should I create another class and handle myself the mapping between this class and the entity? 
Is there a pattern for this?
How to accomplish partial expansion? (i.e. return only the firstName and lastName for the user)

P.S: using @JSONFilter and ObjectMapper to accomplish partial responses seems too heavyweight to me because you loose the beauty of spring data

Comment: If coupling between service and domain entity is what you're concerned about, have a look at Spring Roo (http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo), it can auto generate CRUD service using AspectJ weaving, so all you need to care about is the domain entity

Comment: If your services are exposing domain object to the presentation layer, then you have, by definition, leaking abstraction for the model layer (which is what contains services, domain objects and mappers).